# JQuery not working on my page, although I included the library

Tags: javascript, jquery

JQuery does not work on my page, I have included the library in many different ways(I mean using different links as src all the time, and all of them were correct) and still I get the "$ is not defined".

What else should I try?

Here is a look on the page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- stuff up here css include title, etc -->
    <script scr="../res/jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    //not important code here
</body>
<script>
  function go_login(){
    var username = $('#username').val(); // the error starts at this line!
    ...
</script>
</html>
```

As I said, I tried to include the library from other sources(local and external) and still the same error occurred. (note that I have tested all the sources and the reference link, and they all are and were correct!).

Comment: You are calling `go_login()` before the inclusion of jquery library, but your code doesn't show it. So this should be closed as offtopic > non reproducible problem / typographycal error

Comment: used document on ready?

Comment: `You are calling go_login() before the inclusion of jquery library` that's a HUGE assumption

Comment: I call the go_logic() after including.

Comment: Is the logical assumption when OP said that the path is correct.

Comment: Check the browser developer tools network tab - check that `../res/jquery.js` actually loads successfully

Comment: @StefanSchiffer well, share the complete code. Or your path is incorrect or something you aren't telling us

Comment: Did you mean `src` instead of `scr`?

Comment: @JF seems to be the problem! Maybe I'm blindness LOL

Comment: However, vote to close by typographycal error.

Comment: Omg, I'm and Idiot, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am an idiot, simple syntax error.

Comment: If you delete the question (syntax error not useful to readership) you'll probably get your points back ;-)